# Is a digital lens possible?

Tags: raspicam

I have my raspberry pi cam recording pictures with a resolution of 1280 x 720, but most of the picture area, is un-important for the intended use.

Is there a way of enhancing the resolution, in a small specific area, to give me a narrower field of view with a higher resolution; in effect like a digital lens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution of a camera chip is a fixed thing, essentially given by size and pitch of the actual pixels on that very sensor. There is no such thing as to digitally enhance resolution (CSI-style). You could crop to image to your region of interest. You could also sharpen the image or upscale it, but the that's all no true increase of resolution.

The only thing to use the full resolution of the sensor is to change the optics in front of it aka the objective lens to increase the focal length.

Comment: thought so, but i can not fit a lens in front in the application :(

Comment: You should try to crop your image and hope the resulting resolution is sufficient.